# Spring Cloud Config Brixton.M5 HTTP 406 for yml or properties

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, spring-cloud

In a project, I have the Brixton.M5 bom setup in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencyManagement {

    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:Brixton.M5"
    }

}
```

Spring Cloud Config runs fine and is available to configure the apps.  However, when I try to hit any of the rest endpoints other than the default {app name}/{profile}, I am getting a HTTP 406

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Mar 01 10:57:37 EST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation
```

Or this with curl:

```
curl -s http://10.6.6.162:8888/service-default.yml
{"timestamp":1456847908745,"status":406,"error":"Not Acceptable","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException","message":"Could not find acceptable representation","path":"/service-default.yml"}
```

Is it just a missing dependency? Or is this an issue with Brixton.M5 configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. Try Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Thanks @davesyer that fixed it. It was odd, though, with gradle 2.11, it wasn't refreshing. Had to blow away the gradle caches for it come down correctly. All cleaned up now, thanks.